# Java - Delete each 4th occurrence of a character in a row

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm searching for a way to delete each 4th occurrence of a character (a-zA-Z) *in a row*.

For example, if I have the following string:
`helloooo I am veeeeeeeeery busy right nowww because I am working veeeeeery hard`

I want delete all 4th, 5th, 6th, ... characters in a row. But, in the word `hard`, a 4th `r` occurs, which I do NOT want to delete, because it is not the 4th `r` in a row / it is surrounded with other characters. The result should be:
`hellooo I am veeery busy right nowww because I am working veeery hard`

I have already searched for a way to do this, and I could have found a way to replace/delete the 4th occurrence of a character, but I could not find a way to replace/delete the 4th occurrence of a character *in a row*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want a regex answer? or would a helper function work?

Comment: Function would also work, I think.

Comment: As long as it is efficient and fast and does not consume too much resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can use this replacement based on back-references:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(([a-zA-Z])\\2\\2)\\2+", "$1");
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/4XGxse)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP9fO2/2)

Answer (score 3):

The function may be written like this:

```java
public static String transform(String input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return input;
    } else {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char lastChar = '\0';
        int duplicates = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            final char curChar = input.charAt(i);
            if (curChar == lastChar) {
                duplicates++;
                if (duplicates < 3) {
                    sb.append(curChar);
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(curChar);
                lastChar = curChar;
                duplicates = 0;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I think it's faster than regex.

Answer (score 2):

The regex you want is `((.)\2{2})\2*`. Not quite sure what that is in Java-ese, but what it does is match any single character and then 2 additional instances of that character, followed by any number of additional instances. Then replace it with the contents of the first capture group (`\1`) and you're good to go.

Comment: So do I have to use `"aaaa".replaceAll("((.)\\1{2})\\1*","")` which will give the result `"aaa"`?

Comment: Not quite. I'm not up on Java's regex mechanics, but you need the contents of the second capture group (the outer brackets) as the second argument to `replaceAll`.

Comment: I believe you have capturing group numbers in opposite order.